# Server-Sent Events

Tags: javascript, php

Разбираюсь с  [Server-Sent Events](http://learn.javascript.ru/server-sent-events) но в инструкции сервер на javascript а у меня должен  быть на php. Короче с клиентом всё разобрался а про сервер там почти ничего кроме примера.

1. Чтобы соединение успешно открылось, сервер должен ответить с заголовком Content-Type: text/event-stream, а затем оставить соединение висящим и писать в него сообщения в специальном формате. - Что значит "сервер должен ответить с заголовком Content-Type: text/event-stream" я впринчепе понятия не имею, но в их примере сервера то что нужно нашёл:
    res.writeHead(200, {
          'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
          'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
    });
    Но как это реализовать на php незнаю.
2. Попрошу привести пример отправки сообщения. Опять же у них в сервере эо выглядит так: `res.write('data: ' + ++i + '\n\n');`
    А на php я не знаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А озаботится документации по php не [пробовали](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.header.php)?

```
header("Content-Type: text/event-stream");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
echo "data: "...
```

Comment: да конечно пробовал получилось плохо 
<?php
 echo"Content-Type: text/event-stream";
?>

Comment: echo "data: "... - не совсем понимаю что дальше 
как должно выглядеть собщение:
data: Привет мир!
Вот так ?
echo "data: "Привет мир!;

Comment: @Kirpich643, А Вас ссылка на описание функции header не смутила?

Comment: смутила но там только про header .

Comment: И соединение почему то сразу же закрывается.

Comment: Да, ответ от сервера идёт в виде заголовка(header) и собственно данный (echo "data: "), операция echo "content-type: ..." передаёт тело ответа а надо заголовок.